# Sending more than just an image to blobstore's upload url from Android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blobstore

I've recently been experimenting with uploading images to blobstore. I have the whole process working already and am able to successfully upload images to blobstore. My question is if I can send more than just an image to the upload url? The engine saves my image and then redirects the user to my upload handler. However, I am not sure how to send information (such as user id) to the upload url so that it is then sent to my upload handler. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your callback (successPath) with the information you need (such as user id - assuming you know it by the time your are generating the upload URL) by adding request params or extra path info.